# INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY, insufficient access rights on object id: []

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am having a Insufficient access right error when updating case status through process builder.

Note: Case is selected as Private in sharing setting.

There is a some cases in my application which can have duplicate marked, so when i update any case it will find its duplicate and update the status of duplicate cases also.
So the duplicate case can be created by other user with some different role.

So i am updating a case from process builder, which fire the trigger, which find the duplicate of cases and update the status of the duplicate cases. At that time i am getting this error.

> Unable to apply outcome :Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a0br0000000VSRSDDD; first error: CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER, We can't save this record because the “Process Builder Name” process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details. This error occurred when the flow tried to update records: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: TriggerName: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 500r000676761u4AAA; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY, insufficient access rights on object id: [] () . You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide. Error ID: 1396818543-14465 (22544364): []

What my understanding is this is a sharing rules issue, so wherever any class is calling inside from trigger which is doing any DML operation, i have set this class to `without sharing` keyword. Still i am facing this issue. Can anyone help me about that as i am very new to salesforce. Thanks